# VS2010 Upgrade from VS2008 compile Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

So recently at work we upgraded our project from 2008 to 2010 what gets deployed to our web server compiles fine but what is being compiled for our app server is failing. The error we see is:

> Solution file xxx.sln is from a previous version of this application
>   and must be converted in order to build in this version of the
>   application. To convert the solution, open the solution in this
>   version of the application.

I have googled around and haven't found any thing has worked. I know some of the common csproj  aren't the issue but there are a couple that only exist in this solution so I am looking for a possible cause in those.

Funny is when I build the solution locally all is fine its only when out release team builds it that there is an issue.

Comment: Does the release team also have 2010 installed?

Comment: Are you building the solution from VS2010, or using msbuild? If the latter, you need to have opened the solution in VS2010 once.

Comment: Did you open the .sln from VS2010 client and run through the upgrade wizard to convert it to a VS2010 sln?

Comment: Did you check in all the changes including the sln file to the source control? also when you convert make sure you checkout all project files

Answer (score 1):

I seems the the solution files hasn't been converted to the new Visual Studio environment.